# Removing a Tuple from a list of tuples while iterating a greedy algorithm - python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to write a greedy algorithm and I have a list of tuples:

cow_list = [('Betsy', 9), ('Henrietta', 9), ('Herman', 7), ('Oreo', 6), ('Millie', 5), ('Maggie', 3), ('Moo Moo', 3), ('Milkshake', 2), ('Lola', 2), ('Florence', 2)]

I'm trying to iterate through the list:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cow_list, maxWeight):
transport_name = []
taken_transport = []
not_taken = []
transport_weight = []
for i in range(len(cow_list)):
    total_weight = sum(transport_weight)
    if (total_weight+cow_list[i][1]) <= maxWeight:
        transport_name.append(cow_list[i][0])
        transport_weight.append(cow_list[i][1])
        total_weight += cow_list[i][1]
    elif (total_weight+cow_list[i][1]) > maxWeight:
        taken_transport.append(cow_list[i][0])
```

And what I'm trying to do is delete the first tuple in the list if > maxWeight so the for loop can start the process over again without using that first tuple.

So I want the final result to be:

transport_name = [['Betsy'], ['Henrietta'], ['Herman', 'Maggie'], ['Herman', 'Moo Moo'], ['Herman', 'Milkshake'], etc. with all combinations where the sum of the values is <10.

Please let me know if my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: if > maxWeight ? and from which list you want to delete, whats it name ? and I think you need while loop instead.

Comment: if the total_weight > maxWeight, I want to delete the first tuple in cow_list so the loop can continue finding combinations where total_weight is < max_weight. I think you may be right about a while loop but I'm not sure how to set it up in this particular case. Does that clarify things? Thank you, btw.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't have the 20 reputation needed to comment but I really, really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: I needed to discuss to be able to properly answer but I hope you got some ideas I think ... you can use pop() or slice the list [1:] like I showed you in chat room... and use while loop instead..

Answer (score 0):

A very ad-hoc approach,

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cow_list, maxWeight):
    transport_name = []
    taken_transport = []
    not_taken = []
    transport_weight = []
    for i in range(len(cow_list)):
        # Store an initial element
        temp_name.append(cow_list[i][0])
        temp_weight.append(cow_list[i][1])
        total_weight = sum(temp_weight)

        # Iterate on all the elements to the right
        for j in range(i, len(cow_list)):
            if (total_weight + cow_list[j][1])<= maxWeight:
                temp_name.append(cow_list[j][0])
                temp_weight.append(cow_list[j][1])
                total_weight = sum(temp_weight)
            else:
                taken_temp_transport.append(cow_list[j][0])

        transport_name.append(temp_name)
        transport_weight.append(temp_weight)
        taken_transport.append(taken_temp_transport)
```